# switchMap gives OperatorFunction<unknown, any>' is not assignable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, switchmap

I need to switch a stream to an other stream, so I did

```
 this.appState.domain$.pipe(switchMap(() => of(10))
```

[image]

It gives me an error

```
OperatorFunction<unknown, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type OperatorFunction<unknown, any>' ....
```

For me, the error doesn't really tell me what is happening or how to fix this. I would expect this to work, but something is off. Any suggestions why typescript is complaining?

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closely, you have some mixup between **rxjs** libraries.

One is expecting **/node_modules/rxjs/internal/types/Observable**

vs. **of(10)** returning **/node_modules/rxjs/dist/types/internal/types/Observable**

Check your import line on the "of" operator, make sure its correct.

Comment: Nice catch! I checked the imports but they look ok (see my updated post). I can confirm that it only happens in my angular app and not elsewhere. So your finding should be it, but I guess it is not the import of `of`

Comment: It is solved. I removed `node_modules` and installed it again